# Is it professional to have a game read another file containing data?

Tags: python, file

This question is a little bit complicated, so I will present the situation:

I am currently programming my first real game in Python, let's call it "game.py" which has quite a few characters with various stats and other such data.

As of now, the data is stored inside game.py, but this will become highly inconvenient as the program gets larger and larger, because it will take longer to find said data.

Then it hit me, I should try using "open" to have game.py read a file, let's say "characters.txt", and convert it into the formatting used for the characters in game.py, essentially migrating data from one file to another.

Is this a "professional" solution? Is it better to just leave it in a findable place in game.py, or is there a better solution?

Comment: That's what files are for!

Comment: It is good practice to use a modular design. In a modular design you split up your code in multiple modules and separate your data from your code. So yes, it is "professional" to store character data in a file.

Comment: Actually that will be the right way to do it

Comment: You might look into storing all the information you need in a database, which is a type of file.

Comment: Accept one of the answers you got.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, this is the right way to handle the data of your game.

Games consist of a lot of data: game objects and entities, levels, settings, materials and shaders. These are often represented as text files.

Traditionally XML was used to store these type of elements, however another good alternative is JSON. JSON is simple and should be faster to parse than XML. Storing your game data in a JSON format, allows you to easily [load](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) it into your game and access it like a dictionary.

One problem that this might bring is the fact that one can easily tamper the data, since JSON can be easily read and edited. However it's a great way to get started.
For more advanced approaches you can look into encryption methods or consider storing your data in a binary format.

You might be interested in the following [blog](https://davidwalsh.name/game-json), which goes a bit in detail on how JSON can be used for games.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: the JSON advocacy. XML gives you namespace support -- you can, for instance, use SVG graphics and edit with any SVG editor (ie. Inkscape) in the same document where you have game logic (say, in JavaScript), or templating logic (say, Genshi), or HTML describing layout, or so forth, and all your properly aware tools can refer only to the data that's in a namespace that makes it relevant to that tool.

Comment: ...if the primary goal is compactness or parsing speed, there are very good options focused on either of those as well (I'm personally a fan of http://msgpack.org/); but for someone starting out flexibility, interop, and integration with existing authoring tools can be Damned Good Things, and XML fits the bill nicely.

Comment: ...and then there's XQuery/XPath. If you're working with raw JSON, tools to run structural queries, transforms, &c. across your data just don't exist; with XML, there's a robust ecosystem. To be clear: I don't think JSON is always the wrong tool, or XML is always the right tool, but I think the knee-jerk "XML is overcomplicated!" reaction often comes from a place of not actually being familiar enough to know what benefits those "complexities" add in the first place and (thus) why they're there.

Comment: I agree that XML has a great set of mature tools and techniques available. It was not my intention to put XML in a bad light. I'm just basing my answer on my experience. JSON is an easy starter and personally I love the fact that I can just load it with `data = json.load(data_file)` and access elements with a quick `data['hero']['health']`. JSON is also the format that is presented in many game programming courses aiming at new programmers. Since it's OP's first game, I guess he has no need for namespace support and transformations. Nonetheless, your arguments are valid and appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in another .py file and just import it:

characters_data.py:

```
characters={'name':'Me',....
...
}
```

game.py:

```
from characters_data import characters
print characters['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about end users having an easy time manipulating underlying settings (i.e. "Modding"), then you can try saving the files as binary, using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). If you want to add an additional deterrent, you can add [`cryptography`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/crypto/) to the string before storing it in a file, and just keep the key in the .py file (though if someone was motivated, they could find it by reverse-engineering the main.pyc)